# How to insert a string in array with different manner

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

I have a string like below.
str='014387650'
Now i want to split this string like below and put the value in the array.

```
A[0]=0  
A[1]=01  
A[2]=014  
A[3]=0143  
A[4]=01438  
A[5]=014387  
A[6]=0143876  
A[7]=01438765  
A[8]=014387650
```

Comment: the question is not clear , you want the string '014387650 to put in the array A? using bash? or you want to populate every index of the array A as you have written above?

Comment: yes i want to put the string in the array A using bash in unix platform.

Comment: ok , check the answer , i did it for both the cases

Answer (score 5):

The following should work in `bash`:

```
str='014387650'
arr=()
for ((i=0; i<${#str}; i++)); do
    arr+=("${arr[i-1 < 0 ? 0 : i-1]}${str:$i:1}")
done
```

The result:

```
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${arr[@]}"
<0>
<01>
<014>
<0143>
<01438>
<014387>
<0143876>
<01438765>
<014387650>
```

Comment: I'm confused why you refer back to the previous element instead of just building up the split range on str. It's not wrong, but it seems convoluted to me.

Answer (score 1):

Explicit declaration of an array is done using the declare built-in:

```
  declare -a ARRAYNAME
```

Array variables may also be created using compound assignments in this format:

```
  ARRAY=(value1 value2 ... valueN)
```

in your case:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  str='014387650'
  declare -a A
  for (( c=0; c<${#str}; c++ ))
  do
    A[c]=`echo ${str:0:$(( $c + 1 ))}`
    echo "A[$c]="${A[$c]} 
  done
```

output:

```
   A[0]=0
   A[1]=01
   A[2]=014
   A[3]=0143
   A[4]=01438
   A[5]=014387
   A[6]=0143876
   A[7]=01438765
   A[8]=014387650
```

if you just want to put the string in an array:

```
   declare -a A
   str=014387650
   A=${str[*]}
   echo ${A[*]}
   014387650
   echo ${A[3]}
   4
```

Comment: you don't need the `\`echo `

Comment: yes , its just for showing the output , if you dont want to show the output , you dont need that

Comment: I meant you can do `A[c]=${str:0:$(( $c + 1 ))}` without the `\`echo\`` part.

Comment: ya , you are right , it should also work that way.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
triangle_split() {
  _len=1
  while [ "$_len" -le "${#1}" ]; do
    printf '%.*s\n' "$_len" "$1"
    : "$((_len+=1))"
  done
}

IFS='
'
A=($(triangle_split 014387650))

printf '%s\n' "${A[@]}"
```

Comment: Could you please explain below line. printf '%.*s\n' "$_len" "$1"
    : "$((_len+=1))"

Comment: The first argument to `printf '%.*s\n'` is maximum bytes to be printed, here it's `$_len` variable. `$((_len+=1))` increase `_len` by one. So you got the first, the second, ... until you got the whole string.

Comment: maybe weirder, but: `len=0;while printf "%.$((len+=1))s\n%.d" "$1" "0$((len<${#1}?0:8))"; do :;done 2>/dev/null`

Comment: @mikeserv: tricky, maybe `"0$((len<${#1}?0:8))"` should become `"0$((len<${#1}?0:$((${#1}-1))))"` for more dynamic?

Comment: Thanks it did work.As i have milions of data.since it's taking time.could you please advised using AWK.

Comment: @cuonglm - no it has to be 8 or 9  because 01-7 won't return failure, do `printf %d 08` to see how it works. but that doesn't have anything to do w/ the string len - just octal conversion.

Comment: @mikeserv Ah right, It seem to be a `bash` feature, I tested with `zsh` and confused.

Comment: @cuonglm - it's not a feature - `zsh` doesn't handle octal conversions posixly. shells are spec'd for interpreting numbers as octals in many situations which involve leading 0s.

Comment: @mikeserv: Would you please give me the part in spec documented this one :)

Comment: ok. `printf` is spec'd for interpreting it's arguments as C integer constants. POSIX *(apparently aligned w/ the ANSI standard)* specs integer constants [thus](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtoul.html]): *A decimal constant begins with a non-zero digit, and consists of a sequence of decimal digits. An octal constant consists of the prefix '0' optionally followed by a sequence of the digits '0' to '7' only... [EINVAL] No conversion could be performed.*

Comment: @mikeserv: Thanks, make sense to me after reading it. It's interesting that in emulate sh, `zsh` does return fail but still print the trailing 0. In emulate ksh, it work like normal zsh.

Comment: did you use the `%.d`? when the precision is null a 0 value can't be printed by spec. that EINVAL lib failure is optional strtol() doesn't have have to return error by spec, but can it return an integer type if the conversion doesn't work. the shell's `printf`*is* spec'd only to print up to the last valid digit for a conversion, and nothing more except to stderr and to return with error when a conversion couldn't be made. there are examples of the error output at the open group site.

Comment: @mikeserv: Yes, `zsh -f` then `emulate sh` then `printf '%.d' 08` gave me `zsh: bad math expression: operator expected at <backslash>8'` and number `0` return.

Comment: weird. ive probably seen that too. im *always* getting *bad math expression* in `zsh` and i never even know what it means. eventually i did figure out that `$((${#}==#))` in `zsh` - which is *puzzling*, and that you really shouldnt ever do `echo "some [$q]uoted string"` in `zsh` without doing `echo "some [${q}]uoted string"` - though i still don't have a clue as to why. both of those things always wind up genning the math expression code. it does a lot of other weird stuff, too - i think there's just too much of it for my taste - it's too bloody huge.

Answer (score 1):

Obvious approach: let's loop downward through the array,  chopping one character at a time from the tail of a string variable which is assigned to the successive elements:

```
#!/bin/bash

str="014387650"

while [ ${#str} -gt 0 ] ; do
  A[$((${#str}-1))]=$str
  str=${str%?}
done

printf "%s\n" ${A[*]}
```

Output:

```
0
01
014
0143
01438
014387
0143876
01438765
014387650
```

Since we are Bash-specific, we might as well rephrase the logic using a `for` loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

str="014387650"

for (( i=${#str} - 1; i >= 0; i-- )); do
  A[$i]=$str
  str=${str%?}
done

printf "%s\n" ${A[*]}
```

Comment: is it more obvious than the other one? i would think you would just flip the sign.

Answer (score 0):

You might do:

```sh
set --; src=014387650 OPTIND=1 tgt=
while   getopts : na -"$src"
do      tgt=$tgt$OPTARG
        set "$@" "A[$#]=$tgt"
done;   printf   %s\\n "$@"
```

---

```
A[0]=0
A[1]=01
A[2]=014
A[3]=0143
A[4]=01438
A[5]=014387
A[6]=0143876
A[7]=01438765
A[8]=014387650
```

Answer (score 0):

Obvious approach: fill the array backwards, and chop the last character of the string as we go:

```
#!/bin/bash

str="014387650"

i=${#str}

while [ $i -gt 0 ] ; do
  A[$((--i))]=$str
  str=${str%?}
done

printf "%s\n" ${A[*]}
```

Output:

```
0
01
014
0143
01438
014387
0143876
01438765
014387650
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
#!/bin/bash

a="014387650"

i=0; unset -v A B
while (( i<${#a} ))
do    A[i]=${a:0:i+1}
      B+=("A[$i]=${A[i++]}")
done

printf '%s\n' "${B[@]}"
```

---

Output:

```
A[0]=0
A[1]=01
A[2]=014
A[3]=0143
A[4]=01438
A[5]=014387
A[6]=0143876
A[7]=01438765
A[8]=014387650
```